# How to switch between different API versions without using a route prefix

Tags: rest, go, go-chi

I'm looking for a clean way to maintain two versions of an API that have the same endpoints.

Right now, the easiest way but seems excessive is to have something like

```
  r := chi.NewRouter()
  r.Get("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    version := r.Header.Get("Accept-version")
    if version == "v1" {
      w.Write([]byte("version 1 of api"))
    } else {
      w.Write([]byte("other version of api"))
    }
  })
```

but when you have a couple dozen+ or so endpoints... can get messy

The way that I would like to have it is have a middleware that will fallthrough to the next defined route. So something like

```
  r := chi.NewRouter()
  r.With(UseVersion1).Get("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      w.Write([]byte("version 1 of api"))
    }
  })
  r.With(UseVersion2).Get("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      w.Write([]byte("other version of api"))
    }
  })
```

Is this even possible? Or can someone suggest a better route (pun not intended)

EDIT: I know that prefixing the path is a viable option. I would like to avoid that

Comment: Add version prefix to the path: `/v1/test` and `/v2/test`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would prefer to not have to prefix the path

Comment: alexmac is right Usually we uses prefix, but you can uses midleware if you do't want to add prefix

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified (and simplified) version of Para's answer that doesn't require declaring separate "v1" and "v2" groups. (Our engineering team didn't like having permanent version prefixes on our APIs since that creates more hassle for everyone having a mix of v1 and v2 api paths in their codebase. Toggling a header is much easier, which is also the strategy that the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/about-the-rest-api/api-versions?apiVersion=2022-11-28#specifying-an-api-version) follows for their API versioning).

For the below code, you must add the header `"X-My-Api-Version:2"` to your request in order to get the v2 response instead of the v1 response. (Note I am using the Gin framework in the sample code)

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    v2 := gin.New()
    v2.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "v2/test")
    })

    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(newVersionIfHeaderPresent(v2))
    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "v1/test")
    })

    r.Run(":8081")
}
```

`middleware.go`

```
func newVersionIfHeaderPresent(v2 *gin.Engine) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        version := c.GetHeader("X-My-Api-Version")
        if version == "2" {
            v2.HandleContext(c)
            c.Abort()
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Test requests:

```
user@computer ~ % curl http://localhost:8081/test
v1/test
user@computer ~ % curl http://localhost:8081/test -H "X-My-Api-Version:2"
v2/test
```

Answer (score 0):

alexmac is right Usually we uses prefix, also, you can uses midleware if you do't want to add prefix(ps:Not recommended)

your code have a problem, one url can't use many midleware

follow is a example in gin, in chi , you can write yourself code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Version() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        if c.Request.RequestURI[:2] != "/v" {
            version := c.GetHeader("Accept-version")
            if version == ""{
                version = "v2"
            }
            c.Redirect(302, "/" + version + c.Request.RequestURI)
            c.Abort()
        }else{
            c.Next()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(Version())
    v1 := r.Group("v1")
    v2 := r.Group("v2")

    v1.GET("/test", func (c *gin.Context){
        c.String(200, "v1 test")
    })
    v2.GET("/test", func (c *gin.Context){
        c.String(200, "v2 test")
    })

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

if you don't want to chagne the url you can:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
var(
    r *gin.Engine
)
func Version() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if c.Request.URL.Path[:2] != "/v" {
            version := c.GetHeader("Accept-version")
            if version == ""{
                version = "v2"
            }
            c.Request.URL.Path = "/" + version + c.Request.RequestURI
            r.HandleContext(c)
            c.Abort()
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}

func main() {
    r = gin.New()
    r.Use(Version())
    v1 := r.Group("v1")
    v2 := r.Group("v2")
    v1.GET("/test", func (c *gin.Context){
        c.String(200, "v1/test")
    })
    v2.GET("/test", func (c *gin.Context){
        c.String(200, "v2/test")
    })

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the previous answers about using the request Header to indicate versions: it's useful to note that you don't always have to version the *entire* REST API at once.

Consider if your fundamental REST API structure is still acceptable, but you need to add functionality to an entity which would result in a breaking-change to older clients.

Fictional example. You've created a lending library for books, which has lots of nicely structured API endpoints:

```
/api/books
/api/cardholders/active
/api/cardholders/inactive
/api/locations
/api/loans
```

...where a `loan` entity looks like:

```json
{
    "cardholderId": 123,
    "bookId": "987-654-321"
}
```

You go 21st century and add digital downloads for loans. This means that the `loans` entities now have a *mandatory* field for whether it's digital or physical. So a POST to `loans` *must* have that mandatory extra field:

```json
{
    "cardholderId": 123,
    "bookId": "987-654-321",
    "loanType": "digital" // new and mandatory
}
```

**This doesn't affect the API structure, it only affects the `loans` endpoints, so there's no point versioning the whole API**.

Instead, clients can *opt in* to supporting the new digital loan type, by accessing the same `/api/loans` endpoint but setting a Header to indicate wanting V2. It doesn't matter which Header. One option might be:

`Accept: application/json+loanv2`

This approach also encourages a useful practice:

- Design your REST endpoint structure around your general domain concepts. So, mirroring your high level business processes. These are usually very slow-changing.
- Wrap any implementation-specific concerns into versions of entities, fitting into that existing structure. These can then be faster-changing without breaking the whole structure.

None of these options are perfect for every situation - URL versioning, Header at root level, or Header at entity level. But hopefully we can make informed decisions.